# JavaScript code runs perfectly in FireFox console and not in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

I run test scripts using Selenium JUnit in Eclipse. Now when I add the following JS code into my Java file, test case stops with error "***selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null***"
Script works fine in FireFox console.
I'm new in JavaScript and I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this issue.

```
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(""
                + "some other code that works fine"
                + "var rtxt= document.querySelector('#CSS__RichHtmlField_displayContent');"
                + "rtxt.textContent= '​JavaScript testScript to testCase';");

    } else {
              throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that Firefox waits for the page and information to load before running the script and checking a value. In a Java implementation I think you need to wait before checking values, otherwise you get errors for that things don't exist / haven't loaded yet.

[http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp](http://Explicit%20Wait)

Comment: Now it works! I added Java wait commands (Implicit and Explicit) between js scripts and it worked! Have no idea why it didn't work when I used js delays.